# AndroidLocalization (How can i change my native language telugu as entire application language)

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-typeface

How can I change my native language telugu as entire application language. Actually I tried below for a Button to display in telugu language:

```
Typeface gautami_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gautami.ttf");
tel.setTypeface(gautami_font);
```

but when I preferred to display same language in TabActivity indicators names it throwing error. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is complete code of mine that i tried to implement.

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ActivityStart extends TabActivity {

TextView frst,scnd,thrd;

TabHost tHst;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_start);
    //      frst=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.frsttxt);
    Typeface gautami_font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gautami.ttf");
    frst.setTypeface(gautami_font);
    frst.setText(getString(R.string.first));


    tHst=getTabHost();
    TabSpec tSpc;

    Intent a = new Intent(this,FrameActivity.class);
    tSpc=tHst.newTabSpec("Ram").setIndicator(frst).setContent(a);

    tHst.addTab(tSpc);
    Intent b = new Intent(this,FrameActivity.class);
    tSpc=tHst.newTabSpec("").setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.second)).setContent(b);
    tHst.addTab(tSpc);
    Intent c = new Intent(this,FrameActivity.class);
    tSpc=tHst.newTabSpec("").setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.third)).setContent(c);
    tHst.addTab(tSpc);
}
```

}

error:

```
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.changelanguage/com.example.changelanguage.ActivityStart}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.example.changelanguage.ActivityStart.onCreate(ActivityStart.java:23)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post your logcat..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` at line number 23..so you are getting null value on line 23, which line is line 23 in these lines

```
frst.setTypeface(gautami_font);
frst.setText(getString(R.string.first));
```

if exception at first line try to see the path is correct or not for "gautami.ttf"...it is directly copied to assets or any subfolders are there?

if exception at second line then  put a log before the line to print getstring value...

Comment: directly copied to assets

Comment: even i tried by creating new folder in assets and called "fonts/gautami.ttf"

Comment: is the problem fixed? or still getting the exception?

Comment: still getting exception Vamshi. shall i forward my code 2 u ? if so plz provide your mail id.

Comment: ur id, not visible mine: ram06319@gmail.com just send empty mail so that i can forward